# What is the weapon masterwork progression?

Tags: destiny-2

To Masterwork a weapon after the Forsaken update, you need to progress it's masterworked stat through 10 ranks, with different and presumably increasing prices for each level.

I know the first level costs, glimmer, the second glimmer and legendary shards, with the third costing a masterwork core.

What are all ten levels of masterwork progression? Are the materials needed for each level the same for each weapon? I would like to know how many masterwork cores it takes to complete all ten levels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fully masterwork a legendary item it will cost you: **10,000 Glimmer, 27 Legendary shards, and 17 Masterwork Cores**

There is a thread on [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/DestinyTheGame/comments/95ehtm/), from months ago when masterwork was last changed, and that user fully broke it down here.

[image]

Note that these values could change whenever bungie wishes to adjust or rebalance the game.

Comment: Note that weapons/armor with masterworks can randomly and more rarely appear at higher levels, not only level 1.

Comment: So if you're buying Masterwork Cores from Spider in the same week, you'll need 2,621,420 Legendary Shards :o