# What resources do I need to masterwork an Armour 2.0 item?

Tags: destiny-2

With the release of [Shadowkeep](https://bungiestore.com/products/destiny-2-shadowkeep) the way that armour works has been updated to Armour 2.0.

I've seen that Legendary Shards are required to boost armour energy levels.

With the new [Enhancement Prism](https://destinytracker.com/destiny-2/db/items/4257549984-enhancement-prism) and [Ascendant Shards](https://destinytracker.com/destiny-2/db/items/4257549985-ascendant-shard), available from Banshee-44, what are the resource requirements to progress through the levels of energy to Masterwork a piece of armour?

[Related question about weapon progression](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/345387/what-is-the-weapon-masterwork-progression).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the cost for armor of the listed level. Also ignoring glimmer cost for now.

Legendary Shard (LS), Enhancement Core (EC), Enhancement Prism (EP), Ascendant Shard (AS)

Legendary armor cost:

```
Level | LS | EC | EP | AS
    2 |  1 |  - |  - |  -
    3 |  1 |  - |  - |  -
    4 |  2 |  - |  - |  -
    5 |  2 |  - |  - |  -
    6 |  3 |  1 |  - |  -
    7 |  3 |  2 |  - |  -
    8 |  4 |  - |  1 |  -
    9 |  4 |  - |  2 |  -
   10 |  5 |  - |  - |  1
Total | 25 |  3 |  3 |  1
```

And exotics cost:

```
Level | LS | EC | EP | AS
    2 |  1 |  - |  - |  -
    3 |  2 |  - |  - |  -
    4 |  2 |  - |  - |  -
    5 |  3 |  - |  - |  -
    6 |  3 |  2 |  - |  -
    7 |  4 |  3 |  - |  -
    8 |  4 |  - |  2 |  -
    9 |  5 |  - |  3 |  -
   10 |  6 |  - |  - |  3
Total | 30 |  5 |  5 |  3
```